# Печать этикетки. Выровнять DIVы с текстом по центру, но не выйти за пределы наибольшего по ширине DIV с QR кодом

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой вывод:

[image: QR код и текст]

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы текстовые DIV выравнивались по центру относительно DIV с QR-кодом.

При этом не должно быть фиксированной ширины DIV в пикселях, т.к. вместо QR-кода может быть штрих-код другой ширины и высоты.

По центру страницы также это все не должно располагаться, т.к. тогда этикетка неправильно будет печататься на принтере этикеток.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  max-height: 130px;
}

.line_bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.line_italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
.line_underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.label {
  #max-width: 230px;
}

.line_text {
  text-align: left;
}

.line_qr {
  margin: 2px 0;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="line_text line_base" style="font-size: 8px;">
  Rossignol Pursuit 100 - 170
</div>

<div class="line_text line_bold" style="font-size: 14px;">
  #1612
</div>

<div class="line_qr">
  <svg width="87" height="87" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="elements" fill="black" stroke="none">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="3" height="3" />
      <rect x="3" y="0" width="3" height="3" />
      <!-- ... -->
      <rect x="75" y="84" width="3" height="3" />
      <rect x="84" y="84" width="3" height="3" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="line_text line_base" style="font-size: 10px;">
  +7 (900) 444-55-66
</div>
```

Comment: Посреди html-кода нельзя размещать `<!DOCTYPE svg` или тем более `<?xml`

Comment: А по теме вопроса просто заверните весь контент в один div, ограничив ему ширину через `width: max-content` или `display: inline-block` или `float: left` или какой-нибудь другой подобный костыль, а дальше уже внутри этого div выравнивайте по центру всё подряд

Comment: <!DOCTYPE svg - посреди кода, я недоглядел, вставился при копировании почему то в codepen. Убрал. В исходном коде нет такого

Comment: Кстати фраза «не должно быть фиксированной ширины» выглядит как-то странно — у этикетки должна же быть заранее известная фиксированная ширина в миллиметрах наверное?

Comment: Все получилось спасибо!
Этикетки разных размеров. То уже подгоняется настройкой масштабирования при печати.